# модифицирование метода, наследование

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование

Нужна помощь есть два класса, допустим, черный и цветной металл (цветной - наследник черного) у черного есть метод ввод, в котором пользователь задает имя, плотность и массу, а у цветного металла есть еще величина температура плавления, можно ли сделать так, чтобы метод ввод модифицировался и помимо унаследованных данных из черного металла выводил еще в этом же методе данные наследника ( температуру плавления)? (хз понятно или нет, но сделал максимум, чтобы донести смысл)

```
class BlackMetal
{
private:
    string name;
    int mass;
    float resist;
    float plot;
public:
    int Getx()
    {
        return mass;
    }
    float Gety()
    {
        return resist;
    }
    float Getz()
    {
        return plot;
    }
    string Getn()
    {
        return name;
    }
    void vvod()
    {
        cout << "Введите название металла\n";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Введите кол-во в гр. металла\n";
        mass = getValue();
        cout << "Введите уд. сопротивление металла\n";
        resist = getValue();
        cout << "Введите плотность металла\n";
        plot = getValue();
    }
    void vivod()
    {
        cout << "Имя металла: " << name << " " << "Масса: " << mass << " " << "Уд.сопротивление " << resist << " " << "Плотность: " << plot << endl;
    }

};
class ColorMetal : public BlackMetal
{
private:


string color;
    float UdPlav;
public:
string GetColor()
{
    return color;
}
float GetUdPlav()
{
    return UdPlav;
}
void vvod()
{

    }
};
```

Comment: как и когда инициализируете UdPlav?... Зачем нужно все это наследование, когда можно иметь два режима(вида) и выполнить операции в зависимости от вида?    И  классу вовсе не нужно содержать все эти объекты, он просто  выполняет ввод и вывод...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо это?

```
void ColoorMetal::vvod()
{
    BlackMetal::vvod();
    cout << "Введите температуру плавления\n";
    UdPlav = getValue();
}
```

Только вот цветной металл - это ни разу не черный, их оба лучше наследовать от общего класса "металл"...

Comment: Понял, так и сделаю, просто думал можно модифицировать, но если это лишний гемор, то не стоит

Comment: Насчет металлов я знаю, это я для галочки делаю

Comment: Даже для галочки не стоит привыкать делать неправильно...

Comment: Забавно, сегодня кто-то затаил на меня злобу, и все мои сегодняшние ответы тут же минусуются :)